# Connect to a MySQL server on another server

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services

I have a website hosted by namecheap and trying to move it to AWS. For now, I want to keep using the MySQL server on namecheap. I searched online for solutions and one was to whitelist the AWS ip address in the cpanel. That option doesn't exist in my cpanel.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Move your database. Don't leave it flapping open for anyone to poke and prod. `mysqldump` and restore. Shouldn't take long unless you have >100GB of data.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a user with AWS ip address.

1. Allow specific IP

   `mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to ‘user’@‘12.34.56.78’ identified by ‘user's password’;`
2. Allow IP with wildcard (12.34.0.0/16)

   `mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to ‘user’@‘12.34.%’ identified by ‘user's password’;`
3. Allow all IP

   `mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to ‘user’@‘%’ identified by ‘user's password’`

Applying changes

```
mysql> flush privileges;
```

You have to modify mf.cnf to listen port
comment

```
#bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

in my.cnf

then restart your mysql server